# C# Client/Server returning answer from server to client

Tags: c#, tcp

I've created a simple client/server program which takes an input from the client and returns a answer to the input by looking in the text file  to see if there is an answer associated with the input.

The issue I'm having is that I get the response on the server side but I don't know how to send it back to the client (it just returns the input on the client side).

The second issue is that it will execute once, as in, it will only take in one input. I tried adding a loop but couldn't get it to work.

Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace server
{
    class server
    {
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create Dictionary
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //---Read Text File containing commands ---
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Desktop\potato.txt");
            string line;

            //Splits the text into commands:responses
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] arr = line.Split(';');
                dict.Add(arr[0], arr[1]);
            }
            //Print dictionary TESTING FUNCTION
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Command = {0} Response = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }

            //---Input the port number for clients to conect---
            Console.Write("Input port" + System.Environment.NewLine);
            int PORT_NO = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for Commands");
            listener.Start();

            //---incoming client connected---
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //---read incoming stream---
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //---convert the command data received into a string---
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Command : " + dataReceived);

            //---Search Command and send a response
            string Response;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(dataReceived, out Response))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Response);
            }
            //---write back the response to the client---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending Response : " + Response);
            nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); - there's why you're getting the command you sent back. It's what you're sending back.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that, would nw.stream.Write(Response); work?(probably not) im not sure how to replace the line with the response.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx - However, because it is a Stream, you can use a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx to write to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `Response` to a `byte[]` just as you do in the client sending your request (i.e. `bytesToSend`). E.g.:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Response : " + Response);
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Response);
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

That said, you have made the classic mistake every person does who tries to write TCP code without first reading references about TCP and sockets: you mistakenly believe that when you read from a socket, you will always receive in that single operation every byte that was read. So even with the above fix (which does address the issue on the *server* side), it is possible you will see partial responses on the client side (not as likely when testing locally, but much more likely if you move to running on the Internet or across LANs, and especially as the message size increases).

For low-volume network interaction, you may want to consider wrapping your `NetworkStream` with `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects, and use `ReadLine()` and `WriteLine()` to receive and send data (i.e. use line-breaks as the delimiter for the data).

As for dealing with multiple requests, given the code you have presented here, the simplest approach is to add a loop around the server code *after* the `listener.Start()` method. I.e. containing all the code after that statement, starting with the call to `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` and going to the last statement in the method. However, again this is only appropriate for low-volume network code. If you anticipate clients will need your server to handle multiple requests and especially if in quick succession, what you really want is for the client to maintain the connection, i.e. only connect once and then have it send multiple requests on that same connection.

Similarly, if you want to be able to handle multiple clients at once, you cannot run the server in a single thread. Instead, at the very least you'll need to use the thread-blocking logic you're using now, where you have a new thread created for each client. Better, would be to use the non-blocking API (e.g. `NetworkStream.BeginRead()`, `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync()`, etc. … there are many asynchronous options to choose from), and let .NET deal with the threading for you.

Doing it that way will require significant changes to the server code. You really should look carefully at various samples on MSDN and Stack Overflow to see how this sort of thing is done. I also *strongly* recommend you read through the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It is not specifically about .NET at all, but does cover all of the key details you'll need to know in order to effectively and correctly use the .NET API.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate it, ive started reading the FAQ and learning more about TCP Coding.